# Querying Random 10 Percent for Each Record in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

We audit 10% of files for each of our clients and need to create a SQL script.  I can create a query for each client by using a WHERE statement.  However, I need it run on for each client.  If I did it manually, I would need to run this for each individual client. Is there a way to query the 10% for each client in a script?

> SELECT TOP 10 PERCENT     b.loan_no
>
> FROM borrower b JOIN clients c ON
>   b.clients_id = c.clients_id WHERE
>   b.funded >= '04/01/2011' AND c.dba IN
>   'ABC COMPANY' ORDER BY NEWID()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Select clients_id, Loans.loan_no
From clients As c
    Cross Apply (
                Select Top 10 Percent b.loan_no
                From borrower As b
                Where b.clients_id = c.clients_id
                    And b.funded >= '20110401'
                    And b.dba In( 'ABC Company' )
                Order By NewId()
                ) As Loans
```

Comment: I removed the `And b.dba In( 'ABC Company' )` portion and it works great.  Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

Sample using `master..spt_values` - adjust to your table

```
select a.*
from 
(
    select *,
        rn=ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by type order by newid()),
        COUNT(*) over (partition by type) countPerType
    from master..spt_values
) a
where rn <= ceiling(countPerType*10.0/100)
```

The basic mechanism is to count how many rows there are per partition (client) in one window, and in the other, row_number within each partition, and grab only where the row numbering produced is within the 10% range required.  CEILING is used so that if you had a sample of 2, 10% is 0.2 which is rounded UP to 1, so you always end up with >= 10% of records.